# What does "& 0x7fffffff" mean in "int(time.time()*1000.0) & 0x7FFFFFFF"

Tags: python

I have the following value

```
start = int(time.time()*1000.0) & 0x7FFFFFFF
```

What is the purpose of the `& 0x7FFFFFFF`?

Comment: Is it from a random number generator?

Comment: Masking an integer with `0x7FFFFFFF` ensures that a 32-bit quantity can't be signed (the most significant bit is 0).

Comment: It means you want to retain only the last 31 bits of the resulting value, so it is like calculating in modulo 2^31.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's a bitmask. In low-level computation, it's an efficient way to clear out bits of register. In this case, the mask has all bits of a 32 bit integer set, except the signed bit. The signed bit is the bit that determines if the number is positive or negative. ANDing (`&`) with this mask effectively sets the signed bit to 0, which means the number will always be positive.

`a && b` is `True` when both `a` and `b` are `True`.
`a & b` is `1` when both `a` and `b` are `1`, for each binary digit in a and b.

Python has support for binary literals, with the `0b` prefix. Here are some 3-bit numbers being `and`ed together.

```
>>> 0b101 & 0b110 == 0b100
True
>>> 0b011 & 0b111 == 0b011
True
>>> 0b011 & 0b110 == 0b010
True
```

Answer (score 16):

`0x7FFFFFFF` is a number in hexadecimal (2,147,483,647 in decimal) that represents the maximum positive value for a 32-bit signed binary integer.

The `&` symbol is a [bitwise operator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators), more specifically the `and` operator.

Let's call the value `0x7FFFFFFF` 'A' and the expression `int(time.time()*1000.0)` 'B'.

When you do `'A' & 'B'`, each bit of the output is 1 if the corresponding bit of A AND of B is 1, otherwise it's 0.